# Hide/Remove dashboard settings tab through plugin in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I want to remove wordpress dashboard settings tab using plugin. I don't want users to access settings tab when my plugin is activated. I have google for it and found below code but its not working.

```
function remove_menus(){
  remove_menu_page( 'options-general' );       //Settings tab
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost... You need to specific a full php filename as per the examples

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page

```
remove_menu_page( 'options-general.php' );
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function remove_menus(){
  remove_menu_page( 'options-general.php' );  // slug should be the menu (typically the name of the PHP script for the built in menu item     
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
```

Note: the user can still access the screen if he enters the url directly

Comment: Is it possible to prevent direct url access also ?

Comment: one approach is to check `$pagenow` or [get_current_screen](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen).